# Erro ao modelar XSD

Tags: web-service, xml, xsd

A partir deste código XML, tenho o bloco XSD:

**Código**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/arquivoValidador" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/arquivoValidador" elementFormDefault="qualified">

      <xs:complexType name="teste">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:int" name="numeronfd"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:int" name="codseriedocumento"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:int" name="codnaturezaoperacao"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="codigocidade"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:int" name="inscricaomunicipalemissor"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

Não aparecem os elementos:

**Imagem:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E qual é a dúvida mesmo?

Comment: Os elementos não aparecem!!